# how can I solve problem in installing FLUTTER

Tags: windows, flutter, android-studio, installation, command-prompt

<Running "flutter pub get" in **flutter_tools**...>[image]

Comment: Is it stuck here?

Comment: Its because of your internet speed and maybe its better to try with vpn too.

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I'm stuck here for hours and I don't think it is network's problem :(

Answer (score 0):

It actually takes some time and it also depends on the internet speed and the speed of your computer. Give it some time and it will work.